# Best way to write PHP SQL Update Statement

Tags: php, sql, sql-update

I have this PHP SQL statement:

```
$updateCategory = "UPDATE category 
                   SET name=".$name.", description=".$description.",
                       parent=".$parent.", active=".$active." 
                   WHERE id=".$catID."";
```

What is the best way to write this?

Thanks,

Chris.

Comment: How do you mean? Are you looking for a different query, formatting/layout options, maybe tips on how to use PDO, comments on injection, tips for speed... what is your question?

Comment: This seems pretty subjective, but Michiel Pater's answer is as good as any. You could also look into using prepared statements, which is a good practice and cuts down on the amount of annoying string concatenation you need to do.

Answer (score 14):

I suggest you use prepared statements instead of concatenating the query string together:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE 
           category
        SET
           name=:name,
           description=:description,
           parent=:parent, 
           active=:active
        WHERE
           id=:catID';
```

if you are using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), which I strongly suggest, you would then call it like this:

```
$params = array(
    ':name'        => $name,
    ':description' => $description,
    ':parent'      => $parent,
    ':active'      => $active,
    ':catID'       => $catID
);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

You might ask, "why all this hassle?" The advantages of this approach are quite overwhelming:

- You don't have to care about SQL injection, since the database driver now handles the correct transformation of the input parameters
- You don't have to care about escaping special characters, but you can concentrate on what you want to achieve rather than on how to achieve it :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could format it like this to make it more readable.

```
$updateCategory = "
    UPDATE
        category
    SET
        `name` = '" . $name . "',
        `description` = '" . $description . "',
        `parent` = '" . $parent . "',
        `active` = '" . $active . "'
    WHERE
        `id` = '" . $catID . "'";
```

Comment: why not simply `$name` or `{$name}` without those hard-to-read concatenations?

Comment: @bazmegakapa: I find it more readable because of syntax highlighting.

Comment: OK with that, just a suggestion. I prefer `{$name}` for the same reason actually...

Answer (score 1):

I find that concatenating queries causes me major headaches with syntax errors-- all those quotes and dots sprinked around like pepper.  Here's how I would write the query:

```
$updateCategory = "
    UPDATE category     
    SET catname = '$name', description = '$description', 
        parent = '$parent', active = '$active'
    WHERE id = '$catID'";
```

Note that "name" is a reserved word and should not be used as a column name.  Also if id is an integer, $catID doesn't need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

`$update = "update table_name SET name = '$name', email = '$email', password = '$password', phoneno = '$phoneno' WHERE id = '$id'";`